# object in unreal engine disappear?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brj5R.jpg)so im basically new to blueprints and i am trying to make a game based on collecting trophies and i finished the code, but for some reason when i drag and drop the trophy it disappears, that wasnt an issue before, im also trying to randomize where the object spawns and i was succesful but after i made changes to the trophy code, suddenly it wont spawn at all, here are some screen shots. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC1n1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are destroying object on overlap, right before you respawn the object, you should destroy the trophy only after you spawn new, so destroy function must be called at the end, when other logic is finished.
And the best way to handle such operations is some kind of manager. You may use game mode, level, player controller as trophy manager, anything that will exist from the beggining of play and till the level is closed.